# Pull info from XML in VB.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have used this code which does run:

```vb
Using client As New Net.WebClient
    Dim reqparm As New Specialized.NameValueCollection
    reqparm.Add("username", "username")
    reqparm.Add("password", "password")
    Dim responsebytes = client.UploadValues("www.example.com", "POST", reqparm)
    Dim responsebody = (New Text.UTF8Encoding).GetString(responsebytes)
End Using
```

It returns this xml:

```xml
<params>
<status>...</status>
<error>...</error>
<version>...</version>
<sessionid>...</sessionid>
<sessiontimeout>...</sessiontimeout>
<staffid>...</staffid>
<uniqueid>...</uniqueid>
<option name="...">...</option>
<permission name="...">...</permission>
<variable name="...">...</variable>
</params>
```

I'm looking to grab the session ID and store it in a variable. How would I go about pulling it from the XML?

Comment: Did you try something already? Do you have some code?

Comment: There are as many answers to this as there are programmers in the world.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ton of ways to read XML in .NET, here is one option.

```
Private Function GetSessionId(text As String) As String
    Using StringReader As New StringReader(text)
        Using XmlReader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(StringReader)
            If XmlReader.ReadToFollowing("sessionid") Then
                Return XmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString()
            End If
        End Using
    End Using

    Return String.Empty
End Function
```

The usage would look something like this..

```
Dim SessionId As String = GetSessionId(responsebody)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways, a very simple way for what you looking to do could be done using an XElement object:

VB.NET

```
Dim xmlTree As XElement = <params>
<status>...</status>
<error>...</error>
<version>...</version>
<sessionid>...</sessionid>
<sessiontimeout>...</sessiontimeout>
<staffid>...</staffid>
<uniqueid>...</uniqueid>
<option name="...">...</option>
<permission name="...">...</permission>
<variable name="...">...</variable>
</params>
```

Then you can access the fields like so:

```
Dim result = xmlTree.<status>.Value
```